Is Float 0.0 is Null for Android Bundle?
Im trying to pass mPriceModifier with 0.0 value in Bundle. But get this exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.Float

mPriceModifier initialize
private var mPriceModifier: Double = 0.0

there is only 1 use for mPriceModifier before it goes to Bundle. Anyway with debug mode it shows 0.0 before put it in.
there is the code for bundle
mBundle.apply {
    putFloat("priceModifier", mPriceModifier.toFloat())
}
mNavController.navigate(R.id.action_global_processState, mBundle)

mPriceModifier is NonNullableType. nav_graph also doesnt have "nullable" property for this argument.
Also if i add "if" expression like that
if(mPriceModifier != 0.0){
    mBundle.apply{
       putFloat("priceModifier", mPriceModifier.toFloat())
    }
}

then it will skip this expression but anyway give me this exception

What exactly is mPriceModifier? Where do you declare it? How do you populate it? Note that just because you declare a type as non-nullable, the value still could be null, if the value is set using Java code (including libraries and framework classes).

@CommonsWare upd

How are you reading the bundle? The error is likely to lie there

Not sure if this is the issue, but I would probably declare the variable as float, therefore I don't need to convert from double to float while putting the value into the bundle. Try the following and remove this (mPriceModifier.toFloat())
private var mPriceModifier: Float = 0.0f

Moreover, please do check/share how you read the value. The issue could also be there.
